# Delete every other element with slicing

Tags: python

Consider this:

```
numbers = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

These are correct statements in Python to remove elements:

```
numbers[0:2] = []
numbers[3:5] = []
```

However the statement below is not allowed:

```
numbers[::2] = []
```

> ValueError: attempt to assign sequence of size 0 to extended slice of size 5

What prevents such a statement in Python?

Comment: For contiguous slices, the semantic of assigning an iterable of a differing length  is relatively clear. For non-contiguous slices, less so: imagine `numbers[::2] = [1]`, what is that supposed to mean?

Comment: i guess i'm not seeing the ambiguity. wouldn't it just be `[1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 5, 1, 7, 1, 9]`? what would the alternative interpretation(s)?

Comment: `numbers[0:2]` is a `slice`, while `numbers[::2]` is an `extended slice`. if the question is really about what prevents this and not why it prevents this, then this is the answer

Comment: @tdy what then is the interpretation of `numbers[::2] = [1, 2]`?

Comment: @ExtraFishness `[1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 5, 1, 2, 7, 1, 2, 9]`

Comment: why not `[1, [1, 2], 2, [1,2], 3, [1,2], 4, [1,2], 5...]`? it's ambigous...

Comment: then why is `numbers[3:5] = [1, 2]` not `[0, 1, 2, [1, 2], 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`? so to be more precise, i don't see a difference in ambiguity between slice/extended slice.

Comment: @ExtraFishness so some where in python internals there is a difference betwwen `slices` ans `extended slice`? Can you guide me to documentation for extended slice? or is there a comparison between two somewhere? Thanks.

Comment: @tdy Say the list is `numbers = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]` and then we perform `numbers[::2] = [1, 2]`. The reason it is ambiguous is because there are different ways the assignment could happen, whether `[1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0]` or `[1, 0, 2, 0, None, 0, None, 0, None, 0]` or `[1, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0]` or `[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0]` or `[[1, 2], 0, [1, 2], 0, [1, 2], 0, [1, 2], 0, [1, 2], 0]`. Unlike performing `numbers[3:9] = [1, 2]` which has only 1 meaning, which is to remove items 3:9 then put [1,2] in its place producing `[0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0]`.

Comment: I'm an experienced C++ developer. Why I have such hard time to understand how Python interpreter thinks?

Comment: @NielGodfreyPonciano Any of those interpretations could just as easily apply to `numbers[3:9] = [1,2]` though: `[0,0,0,1,2,1,2,1,2,0]`, `[0,0,0,1,2,None,None,None,None,0]`, `[0,0,0,[1,2],[1,2],[1,2],[1,2],[1,2],[1,2],0]`, etc. To me the only explanation that's made sense is what @kaya3 said about how the RHS is only supposed to get used *once* on the LHS during slice assignment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ValueError: attempt to assign sequence of size 0 to extended slice of size 5
>
> What prevents such a statement in Python?

It is noted in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types) that the replacement must have the same length for the case where there is an explicit step (which is `2` in your case).

| Operation | Result | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| s[i:j] = t | slice of s from i to j is replaced by the contents of the iterable t |  |
| s[i:j:k] = t | the elements of s[i:j:k] are replaced by those of t | (1) **t must have the same length as the slice it is replacing.** |

The correct way is also documented there.

| Operation | Result | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| del s[i:j] | same as s[i:j] = [] |  |
| del s[i:j:k] | removes the elements of s[i:j:k] from the list |  |

Code:

```
numbers = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
del numbers[::2]
print(numbers)
```

Output:

```
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no need for `numbers[::2] = []` to have the behaviour of deleting every second element, because you can already do that by writing `numbers[:] = numbers[1::2]`. If instead you want to (e.g.) replace every second element with the value `1`, you can write one of the below, which are explicit about their behaviour.

```
for i in range(0, len(numbers), 2):
    numbers[i] = 1

# or:
numbers[::2] = [1] * len(numbers[::2])
```

It is not obvious what the correct behaviour should be for assigning `m` elements to a non-contiguous slice of `n` list locations when `m != n`. In the comments you propose a possible behaviour, but your proposal is not consistent with how slice assignment works in other cases (normally, each element on the right-hand side gets used *once* on the left-hand side) and certainly doesn't fulfil the [principle of least astonishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment). In cases like this, I think there is *no* (non-raising) behaviour that most people would expect, so raising an error is the best option.

Comment: i'm still not seeing how the proposed extended slice assignment differs from the current slice assignment behavior. e.g., `numbers[3:5] = [0,0,0,0]` currently gives `[0,1,2,0,0,0,0,5,6,7,8,9]`, so to me it seems consistent that `numbers[::2] = [0,0,0,0]` would give `[0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,7,0,0,0,0,9]`.

Comment: @tdy In `numbers[3:5] = [a,b,c,d]` each of `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` occurs once in the right-hand list and will occur once in the left-hand list after the assignment. Normal slice assignment cannot duplicate values.

Comment: ah ok, i see now

Comment: @tdy Also consider the case `numbers[::2] = [5, 6, 7, 8]` which would do rather different things for lists of length 7 and 8 compared to lists of other lengths.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a new list with the slicing already mentioned in other answers:

```
numbers = numbers[1::2]
```

if you work on the same list you incur into heavy performance loss because inserting or deleting (not appending!) an element to a list is O(N). Since you have O(N) for each insertion and you have N/2 insertions your total cost is O(N**2). You really don't want that cost.
Creating a new list with the output of the slicing, on the other hand, has just O(N) total cost.